# Different trend test result with modifiedmk and zyp package in R

Tags: r, regression

I am running two sen slope trend tests in R, the first with the modifiedmk package and the second with the zyp package.  I don't understand why with the zyp package the resulting raster `raster.mkt2` is empty.

This is my code:

```
library(Kendall)
library(zyp)
library(gimms)
library(raster)
library(rgdal)
library(modifiedmk)
library(rkt)

#create a fake raster
r = raster(nrow = 50, ncol = 50)
r[] = sample(seq(from = 1, to = 1000, by = 1), size = ncell(r), replace = TRUE)

#stack it
final_stacked = stack(r,r*2,r*3,r*4)

#function with modifiedmk
tsfun <- function(x, na.rm) {
  if(all(is.na(x))){return(NaN)}
  return(pwmk(x)[["Sen's Slope"]])
}

#function with zyp
tsfun2 <- function(x, na.rm) {
  if(all(is.na(x))){return(NaN)}
  return(zyp.trend.vector(x)[["trend"]])
}


raster.mkt1 <- calc(final_stacked, fun=tsfun, na.rm = TRUE) 
raster.mkt2 <- calc(final_stacked, fun = tsfun2, na.rm = TRUE)

plot(raster.mkt1)
plot(raster.mkt2)
```

EDIT:

changing this line `final_stacked = stack(r,r*3,r*8,r*9, r*20, r*40, r*55, r*66)` so that it isn't linear still leads to different results.

```
#mean of modifiedmk output
m1 = cellStats(raster.mkt1, stat = 'mean', na.rm = TRUE)

#mean of zyp output
m2 = cellStats(raster.mkt2, stat = 'mean', na.rm = TRUE)
```

returns 2696 vs 5252

To further clarify lets pull a random vector from `final_stacked`

```
t = final_stacked[10,10][,]
```

returns:

```
layer.1 layer.2 layer.3 layer.4 layer.5 layer.6 layer.7 layer.8 
    841    2523    6728    7569   16820   33640   46255   55506
```

`pwmk(t)` returns:

```
Z-Value.layer.3      Sen's Slope old. Sen's Slope  P-value.layer.3        S.layer.3           Var(S)      Tau.layer.3 
    2.703381e+00     4.512682e+03     8.788450e+03     6.863795e-03     1.900000e+01     4.433333e+01     9.047619e-01
```

and `zyp.trend.vector(t)` returns:

```
  lbound         trend        trendp        ubound           tau           sig         nruns       autocor    valid_frac 
 3.994750e+03  8.788450e+03  7.030760e+04  1.198425e+04  9.047619e-01  6.863832e-03  1.000000e+00  4.535428e-01  1.000000e+00 
       linear     intercept 
 8.229786e+03 -1.717743e+04
```

So they match, but `raster.mkt1[10,10]` returns 4512 while `raster.mkt2[10,10]` returns 8788

Comment: Tip: set a seed with e.g. `set.seed(12345)` before creating random rasters so we all get the same numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Always* check your function on some sample values first:

```
> final_stacked[1,1,]
     layer.1 layer.2 layer.3 layer.4
[1,]     796    1592    2388    3184

> zyp.trend.vector(final_stacked[1,1,])
    lbound      trend     trendp     ubound        tau        sig      nruns 
        NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA 
   autocor valid_frac     linear  intercept 
        NA         NA         NA         NA
```

So your raster is all `NA`. I don't know what `zyp.trend.vector` is computing (I'll assume you do, or you wouldn't be using it) but it looks like it is degenerate on linear values:

```
> zyp.trend.vector(c(1,2,3,4,5))
    lbound      trend     trendp     ubound        tau        sig      nruns 
        NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA 
   autocor valid_frac     linear  intercept 
        NA         NA         NA         NA
```

If the values aren't linear then you get numbers out:

```
> zyp.trend.vector(c(1,3,3,4,5))
     lbound       trend      trendp      ubound         tau         sig 
 0.00000000  1.00000000  5.00000000  1.00000000  0.99999994  0.08942938 
      nruns     autocor  valid_frac      linear   intercept 
 1.00000000 -0.30000000  1.00000000  0.90000000  0.00000000 
>
```

So your constructed data is the problem.

Comment: If I change this line `final_stacked = stack(r,r*3,r*8,r*9, r*20, r*40, r*55, r*66)` so it isn't linear the result is that the zyp package has on average a slope twice as large as the modifiedmk package

Comment: Well then that's a different question about the interpretation of the outputs of those two methods. You can illustrate that without needing rasters. Try http://stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: To me it seems a problem of using rasters, I will add an update in a minute to illustrate and If you still disagree I will re-approve your answer.  I do appreciate your help so far.

Comment: If I do `d = c(1,5,4,7,8)` then `pwmk(d)` and `zyp.trend.vector(d)` are very different.  I don't know what these methods are fitting, but I would hazard a guess at "not the same thing". Read the docs carefully.

Comment: ah I see so some vectors are different.

Comment: "trend" and "Old Sen's Slope" are the same, but you are comparing "trend" and "Sen's Slope" which aren't...

Comment: I have seen that switch depending on sample, I think I found out why it is and yes this should have been on cross validated. Thanks again.